# Is it OK to use two layout methods (Floats and Flexbox) on the same style sheet?

Tags: css, flexbox

Is using two layout strategies a bad practice?

I am having issues with one section in my style sheet using the Flexbox method, and would rather use the Float method and it's properties on it.

However on another section Flexbox helps me do exactly what I want it to do.

Comment: you can add your code showcasing you problem either as a [snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/356678/stack-overflow-run-code-snippet) or a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) and we'll be up to the task :)

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using multiple layout methods on the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Floats, flex, and grids all have their purposes.  So no, there's nothing inherently wrong with mixing and matching.  You use the right tool for the job.